# Does fitting Simple LogisticRegression with the predictors to find the relationship with the Response make sense?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, p-value, model-selection, logit

Machine Learning newbie here.  My question is quite straight forward, does it make sense to fit simple logistic regression between each of my predictors and response, and then picking up the predictors that show significant relationship with the response for building my further models?  I do understand that some of the predictors will lose significance when used with other predictors.

Comment: If you ''drop'' relevant predictors in a logistic regression, then the estimates of the coefficients of the remaining predictor(s) is (are) biased.  So what you are doing is testing the signifinance based on a biased estimate.  This is not a good idea. Note that for a logistic regression the bias also arises when the predictors are independent.

Comment: Hey thanks. So how do you suggest I should go about finding relevant predictors. Also I want to mention, is there a chance that predictors with very almost no relation to the response(high pvalue), can become significant in the influence of other variables?Also I want to mention my dataset has  quite a class imbalance.

Comment: see 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 and 4.4 of this link http://resource.heartonline.cn/20150528/1_3kOQSTg.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You should use an information criterion (Akaike, Schwartz, etc.) to compare the various candidate models. Just taking some significant variables and combining them with others as you go can be considered a flavor of p-hacking.

Just make sure the criterion you use adequately reflects your tolerance for trading a parsimonious model for more predictive power. Also, if you are not testing "nested" models, be sure your information criterion is still valid (a simple F-test, for instance, would not be).